# generating interactive HTML tables with python

Tags: jquery, python, pandas

Just wondering if there is a package in python which is similar in capabilities to ReportingTools in R.

For example take a data.frame from pandas and directly spit out a HTML5 based interactive data table. Something similar or exactly as jquery based [data tables](http://datatables.net/)

Thanks!
-Abhi